# MailGun: Add data variables to email

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun

Im sending emails through Node.js using MailGun. I want to add custom data variables that contain data from database send it as part of email body. Based on my research I need to use `recipient-variables`. But the problem is that `recipient-variables` require the `email` of recipient as the `key` of the object like so:

```
{
   "user1@example.com" : {"unique_id": "ABC123456789"},
   "user2@example.com" : {"unique_id": "ZXY987654321"}
}
```

**Now the data I'm getting from my database is this:**

```
{ email: 'myemail@something.com', projects: [ 'aqeqw weqw ', 'title here' ]}
```

**Whereas MailGun requires this (which seems weird to me):**

```
{'myemail@something.com': { email: 'myemail@something.com', projects: [ 'aqeqw weqw ', 'title here' ]}}
```

How can I set the key of object I'm receiving from the database as the email?

**FYI my code for MailGun:**

```
let data = {
                from: 'My App <donotreply@myapp.com>',
                to: data.email,
                subject: 'Reminder Email',
                'recipient-variables': {data},
                html: '<html style="color: red; font-size: 20px; background-color: aqua">Inline image here:<p style="">Your project list and your name is %recipient.projects%</p></html>',
            };

            mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {

                console.log(body);

            });
```

Comment: You can do something like `var a = { email: 'myemail@something.com', projects: [ 'aqeqw weqw ', 'title here' ]}; var b = {[a.email] : a}` then inside `b` you will have `{'myemail@something.com': { email: 'myemail@something.com', projects: [ 'aqeqw weqw ', 'title here' ]}}`

Comment: @codtex perfect. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like this, with an intermediate object:

```
let obj = {
  email: 'myemail@something.com',
  projects: [ 'aqeqw weqw ', 'title here' ]
}

let final = {}
final[obj.email] = obj

console.log(final)
/*  {
      'myemail@something.com': 
      {
        email: 'myemail@something.com',
        projects: [ 'aqeqw weqw ', 'title here' ]
      }
    }
*/
```

Comment: Ah perfect. thanks this worked. I'll accept the answer. Any chance you know how to list array values in Mailgun email body? Currently I'm doing `%recipient.projects%` within the body but that displays `[u'aqeqw weqw ', u'aqeqw weqw ', u'james title']`.

Comment: Don't know well the Mailgun api, but from the [doc](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#manual-customdata), it seems you have to format your data as JSON.